# Why is the jquery option selection not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I am currently building a custom control using javascript and JQuery and I have the following function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').each(function() {
        var parent = this;
        $('#comboBoxData li').on('click', 'li', function() {
            alert('found');
            var value = $(this).prop('id');
            alert(value);
            $(parent).val(value);
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the Markup:

```
<select style="display:none">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option vlaue='2'>2</option>
</select>
<ul id="comboBoxData">
    <li id='1'>1</li>
    <li id='2'>2</li>
</ul>
```

I want that when I click the '#comboBoxData li' element the element's ID attribute is used to select an option from the parent input. I have verified that the 'value' variable is populating with the correct data and that the function itself is being reached but for some reason the option is not being selected. What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you show `$(parent)` declaration??

Comment: You also don't need to loop through each item to attach the click event. You can simply do `$('#comboBoxData li').bind('click' [...]);`

Comment: Does this work for you ? http://jsfiddle.net/s6DfL/5/ thanks

Comment: @JamieDixon - Better yet, delegate the event handler to the `ul` so you only have one, rather than one for every `li` element.

Comment: I have added the '$(parent)' declaration to my question

Comment: @JamieDixon thanks for the suggestion mate, I'll update accordingly.

Comment: @JamesAllardice How do I delegate the event handler to the UL?

Comment: @WilliamCalleja - Use `on` (or `delegate` for older versions of jQuery): `$("#comboBoxData").on("click", "li", eventHandler);`

Comment: @JamesAllardice Thanks mate, my problem's still present but the code's easier to maintain now.

Comment: I've tried the code on fiddle and for some reason when the 'select' element is invisible through the display:none, it doesn't change the selected option, why?

Comment: Ok managed to fix it, had a wrong selector.

Comment: @WilliamCalleja I've posted an answer to offer another way of doing this that might better suit your needs. Let me know if this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking at your code and thought I'd post my version of this.

By the looks of it, you want to have more than one `select` list impliment this enhancement. Also, since this is an enhancement I believe the `ul` should be generate on-the-fly. Here's the code and a demo:

```
$('.selectEnhance').each(function (){

    // Setup
    $selectElement = $(this);
    $selectElement.css("display","none");

    // Build the list
    var $listEnhancement = $(buildListEnhancement($(this)));

    // Attach events
    $listEnhancement.find('li').click({selectElement: $selectElement}, function(event){
       event.data.selectElement.val($(this).text());
    });

    // Insert into DOM
    $(this).after($listEnhancement);
});
```

and a basic function to build our `ul` from the `select` item:

```
function buildListEnhancement(selectElement)
{
          var listElements = "";
          selectElement.find('option').each(
            function(){
                   listElements += "<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>";
            });

        return "<ul>" + listElements + "</ul>";
}
```

You can now simple give a class name to the `select` elements that you want to enhance ( `class="selectEnhance"`)

[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/fvkJU/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code, you'll see it works:

```
$('#comboBoxData li').each(function () {
          $(this).bind('click', function () {
          var value = $(this).prop('id');
          $(this).parent().prev("select").val(value);
     });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/quAQm/9/

Comment: I apologise, I used 'parent' as a variable name and not as the actual fucntion parent(). This must have confused a lot of people. Essentially the 'parent' variable is storing the reference to the element

Answer (score 0):

The combobox in your HTML example is not the parent element of `<ul>`. You need to use th `prev()` method of jQuery to travel back to the previous sibling, which in this case is your select box.

```
$('#comboBoxData li').bind('click', function () {                         
   var value = $(this).prop('id');                         
   $(this).parent().prev().val(value);    
});
```

**Edit:**

Forgot that your binding your click event to the each `li` so you do need the `parent()` selector first then the `prev()` selector to get to the combobox

Comment: Hi, Will `$(this).prev('select')` select the `select` tag or you need to specify `$(this).parent('ul').prev('select')`?? Please let me know as i also give full location to select element in my DOM

Comment: @Murtaza Please see my edit, you do still need to use the `parent()` selector. My mistake :(

Comment: Ya i knew that we mention the selector very specific.. otherwise it never selects proper element. seeing your answer i thought you are wrong here but I was not confident on my word so confirmed from you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `parent` recognition code iw wrong. This works  for me:

```
$('#comboBoxData li').click(function () {
   var value = $(this).prop('id');
   $(this).parent().prev().val(value);
});
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/6PJdU/

Comment: I apologise, I used 'parent' as a variable name and not as the actual fucntion parent(). This must have confused a lot of people. Essentially the 'parent' variable is storing the reference to the element

Answer (score 0):

I'm not jQuery expert, but the logic looks a little wrong to me. Off the top of my head (need to check the attribute selector and this may be over complicating it) this might help you progress...

```
$("#comboBoxData li").on("click", function(e) {
  var value = $(this).attr("id");
  var option = $(parent).find("option[value='" + value + "']");
  option.attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

One key point here being, though not necessarily directly related to your problem, is that you can bind on a 'set' of elements, and don't need to loop each of those elements to bind individual elements to the same event. Importantly, I think, what I'm doing is explicitly specifying the `selected` attribute of the option rather than specify the `val` of the select element.

Answer (score 0):

With special thanks to James Allardice and Jamie Dixon. The following markup fixed my issue:

```
$('#comboBoxData').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var value = $(this).prop('id');
    $(parent).val(value);
});
```